# Decode JSON response

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get some prices data from JSON response and save it in users defaults...

the prices class is:

```
  import Foundation

struct Prices : Decodable{
let id, id_service: Int
let nationality: String
let price: Int
let createdAt: String?
let updatedAt: String?
}

class Price : NSObject, NSCoding {
var id, id_service: Int
var nationality: String
var price: Int
var createdAt: String?
var updatedAt: String?


init(id: Int, id_service: Int, nationality: String, price: Int) {
    self.id = id
    self.id_service = id_service
    self.nationality = nationality
    self.price = price

}

required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let id = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "id")
    let id_service = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "id_service")
    let nationality = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "nationality") as! String
    let price = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "price")
    self.init(id: id, id_service: id_service, nationality: nationality, price: price)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
    aCoder.encode(id_service, forKey: "id_service")
    aCoder.encode(nationality, forKey: "nationality")
    aCoder.encode(price, forKey: "price")
}

}
```

and the method i'm calling to do this is:

```
   func GetPrices() {

let todoEndpoint: String = "my link"
guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
    print("Error: cannot create URL")
    return
}
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("error calling GET on /public/api/services")
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        return
    }
    do {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let prices1 = try decoder.decode([Prices].self, from: responseData)
        print("1")
        var prices = [Price]()
        for price in prices1{
            let newprice = Price(id: price.id, id_service: price.id_service,nationality: price.nationality, price: price.price)
            print("2")
            prices.append(newprice)
             print(newprice.nationality)
        }


        var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: prices)
        userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "prices")
        userDefaults.synchronize()

        let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "prices") as! Data
        let decodedPrice = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Price]

        for price in decodedPrice {
            print(price.nationality)
        }


    } catch  {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        return
    }
}
task.resume()
}
```

and the JSON i have is like this (its now have only one.. but its an array):

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "id_service": 2,
    "nationality": "Phili",
    "price": 150,
    "created_at": "2018-04-23 11:43:40",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-23 11:43:40",
    "deleted_at": null
}
]
```

The problem is that i'm always getting this message: error trying to convert data to JSON

Why? what i'm doing wrong? how to solve this?

Comment: in your catch block `print(error.localizedDescription)` there is no need to loop through prices1 and make a new array, it is already an array

Comment: @Scriptable got this error: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

Comment: it is missing? Try to print data or data.count

Comment: The `convertFromSnakeCase` option decodes `id_service` to `idService`

Comment: And why do you use a class and a struct containing the same data? Save the JSON as `Data` in `UserDefaults` and decode it into the struct when reading it.

Comment: you can define the `enum` of keys inside the structure, like e.g. `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case createAtRawDate = "create_at" }`, etc... you can read more about encoding/decoding in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Comment: @vadian how to do that? x_x im new to this sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decoding with .convertFromSnakeCase so your properties should be in camel casing.

```
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

ref. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder.keydecodingstrategy/2949105-convertfromsnakecase

so for a fix, change your property name id_service to idService, like this.

```
struct Prices : Decodable{
    let id, idService: Int
    let nationality: String
    let price: Int
    let createdAt: String?
    let updatedAt: String?
}
```

for better understanding, you may review .useDefaultKeys too https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder.keydecodingstrategy/2949131-usedefaultkeys

Comment: Thank you so much!